# Keep imported python module "fresh"

Tags: python, python-import

Ok, so I have the following question:

I have the following:
x.py:

```
from y import aFunc
```

y.py:

```
from z import aDict
```

Now, x runs on a run,sleep,repeat schedule. It then calls aFunc on certain files. aFunc uses the values in aDict and then returns.

aDict is in a python module that is managed by a user in the econ department. I understand that import is called once and then cached. Even if I was to put the import statement inside aFunc it'll still be imported only once and then cached (please correct me if I'm wrong).

But I want to be able to pick up any changes to aDict on the fly, in other words, I'd like to re-import z.aDict every time x called y.aFunc

Any advice will be much appreciated!

Comment: It sounds like you're using modules for data. That sounds like a bad idea, especially if someone is in the middle of updating the `z.py` file when you try to import it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use reload but you can't use

```
from z import aDict
```

You can do something like :

```
reload(z)
#do something with z.aDict here
```

Comment: that is true, thanks for the advice. and you'll get the "answer" mark

Comment: To keep your names unqualified as they are, just do `aDict = z.aDict` after each reload.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I found the answer. It is with reload(aDict) which seems to keep things fresh... Hopefully this helps others though!

Edit: Whoops! reload can only take modules. So what I ended up doing was importing the entire module and then prefixing z.aDict in my code.

[reload from python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=reload#reload)

Comment: reload() can only take modules as an argument

Comment: It would be best if you pressed the green outlined checkmark under @sedavidw's answer. It would mark the answer 'accepted'.